# What was Poincaré's original idea of the fundamental group?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, math-history, fundamental-groups

The question ''How did Poincaré discover the fundamental group?'' has been asked before [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/how-did-poincar%C3%A9-discover-the-fundamental-group). But I don't understand the idea of the fundamental group from Poincaré point of view in his paper.  I read the Hatcher's book concerning the idea of fundamental group. But I think that this is different from original idea from Poincaré.  Is there any reference which explains Poincaré idea perfectly and originally? I want to understand what are the Betti numbers and the fundamental group suppose to do from Poincare point of view and what is difference between them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See Dieudonne's book "A History of Algebraic and Differential Topology".

Comment: You could read the review MR2723194 (2011j:01017)  01A75 (01A60  55-03  57-03)
Poincar´e, Henri
Papers on topology.
Analysis situs and its ﬁve supplements.
Translated and with an introduction by John Stillwell.

Comment: [Papers on topology. Analysis situs and its ﬁve supplements](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/poincare2009.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [Analysis situs website](http://analysis-situs.math.cnrs.fr/) is exactly what you're looking after.

Small catch, though: it's in French.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.